# How to add stickers to Samsung Keyboard?

Tags: samsung, keyboard

I have made a sticker pack for Telegram.. Is there a way to integrate those stickers into Samsung Keyboard ? If so, how ?

(Stickers are private, so no publishing to Galaxy Store.I have no root on my S8)